# Android Camera2 : How to access every single frames while Recording video?

Tags: android, video, android-camera2

My goal is to get access to every single frame while recording a video.
I'm using `Camera2` API.

What I want is to take every single frame while recording, and the frames should be exactly equal to each frame of result video, not preview frames.

Of course I can access each frame after recording is over using tools like OpenCV or FFMPEG or something, but right now I need to get them real-time while recording.

`Bitmap`, `Image`, `ByteBuffer`, `byte[]` or as file, whatever type is OK if I can access each data.

I've searched some tutorials and found [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuvVpsFc77w&list=PL9jCwTXYWjDIHNEGtsRdCTk79I9-95TbJ), especially [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMkwhX5-t4Y&list=PL9jCwTXYWjDIHNEGtsRdCTk79I9-95TbJ&index=18), but that's not exactly what I need.
That tutorial includes how to take a photo while recording a video.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You mean you want to output all frames as files (or raw bitmaps) in real time? I don't think you'll be able to do that due to media decoder/IO constraints.

Comment: @Pawel Not only as file, just any type of data container class such as `byte[]` , `ByteBuffer`, `Image`, etc will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in general the exact video frames are only sent to the video encoder.  You can of course decode the video after each encoded frame is output from a MediaCodec, but that's a bit expensive.

Alternatively, you can try using an [ImageReader with usage flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader?hl=en#newInstance(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20long)), which is only possible on fairly recent Android versions, and use both the USAGE_CPU_READ_OFTEN and USAGE_VIDEO_ENCODE usage flags, and format YUV_420_888.  That should be as close as you can get to the 'normal' video recording output, but it may not be exactly identical, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. I gotta go deeper into the usage flags.